# Testing Electron app using selenium, java in MacOS environment

Tags: java, macos, selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver

Is there sample java code for launching electron apps using selenium-chromedriver?  Here's where I am at this point.  My code brings up the electron app, and I can view the webElements on that page, but doesn't launch the app I need to test.  I can drag the app over to the electron window and it launches, but the WebDriver doesn't point to it.

```
private void electronTest() throws Exception {

    //select electron-chromedriver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/username/work/node_modules/electron-chromedriver/bin/chromedriver");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // path for Electron
    options.setBinary("/Users/username/work/app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron");
    // I have tried both the folder and the app
    options.addArguments("/Users/username/work/app/out/packages/mac/electronApplication.app");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    // have also tried...
    //driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9515"), capabilities);

    // Electron page appears, but doesn't launch the Electron app

    // driver is pointing to the electron page elements even if I drag the app to launch it
    String screenText = " [" + driver.findElement(By.tagName("BODY")).getText().replace("\n", "][") + "]";
    System.out.println("screenText " + screenText);
}
```

Comment: Making progress...   Instead of launching Electron and trying to pass the path to the build, I've built the app and I'm setting the binary to the MacOS build within the .app:        options.setBinary("/Users/username/work/ape/out/packages/mac/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName");   This now brings up the app itself, but it is necessary to grab the second window handle and do a driver.switchTo when the window appears.

Answer (score 1):

I can give an example that works perfectly on macOS, since I have been testing them lately.

```
public void electronTest()
{
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to the chromedriver");// You can skip this if chromedriver is already included in the PATH.

   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setBinary("/Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);


  // Now, your electron app would have been opened. 
  // Now if you open the dev tools using CMD+ALT+I you would notice two dev tools and first one being for the electron shell. We need to switch to the second window handle. Let's do that.

    for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles())
      {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle); // Since there are two window handles this would switch to last one(which is second one). You can also explicitly provide the window number.
      }

   // Let's navigate to a page
    driver.navigate().to(URL);
    // If you inspect using the Dev Tools, you would notice the second window Dev Tools corresponds to actual page you have opened.
    // From here you can write the usual selenium script and it will work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read how [Using Selenium and WebDriver](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.html). I normally don't paste a link but you should probably read this.  The other chapters will likely be useful to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample for launching electron application with seleniumWebDriver + Java on MacOS

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "ChromeDriverPath");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(binaryPath);
    options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
    options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
    options.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the same method on the remote driver with the help of selenium grid?
My application is an electron-based messaging application and needs to send-receive message between two application. I can do anything on my local machine, send IMs, use all the buttons, login-logout etc. but when it comes to using the remote driver which is set for the node machine, even though app's binary is invoked and the app is launched, the remote driver cannot do anything,

```
public class remotetest {
WebDriver Rdriver;
@Test
public void launch() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\work\\grid\\chromedriver.exe"); // chromedriver path

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("D:\\Users\\myol\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\ConnectMe_S4B2015\\Connect Me S4B2015.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);

    WebDriver Rdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        for (String hand : Rdriver.getWindowHandles()) {

        Rdriver.switchTo().window(hand);
        }

    Rdriver.findElement(By.id("username-kandy")).sendKeys("2311");




}
```

Comment: I found out that I need to run a chrome version lover than 2.40.    "DevTools running inside Chrome can allocate a remote debugging port, and then put the port number into a file named DevToolsActivePort in the user data directory. In the case of Electron application, ChromeDriver wasn't able to find this DevToolsActivePort file, so apparently Electron doesn't have the code to create this file. It might be necessary to update the DevTools server inside Electron to create this file."

Comment: this is the link that helped me https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2489&q=DevToolsActivePort%20file%20doesn%27t%20exist&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary